# Gibbs potential and phase transitions

Tags: thermodynamics, phase-transition

I'm studying phase transitions on Callen's book *Thermodynamics and an Introduction to Thermostatistics* (chapter 9, section 9.1) but I had some problems while trying to understand the role of the presence of multiple minima in the Gibbs free energy.

In the first part of the chapter, Callen makes this example: imagine a vessel of water vapor at a pressure of 1 atm and at a temperature somewhat above 373.15 K, that is slightly above the boiling point. Now consider a small subsystem consisting of a spherical region containing one milligram of water. The radius of this region can change depending on the density of vapor.
Callen arguments that this region is in effective contact with a thermal reservoir and a pressure reservoir. Therefore, the equilibrium of this small subsystem is determined by the minimization of the Gibbs potential G(T,P,N) of the subsystem itself.

My first question is this: How can we minimize G(T,P,N) when T and P are constant (the subsystem is in contact with a thermal and pressure reservoir) and N is constant too (the subsystem contains exactly 1 mg of water)?

After that, Callen continues: "The two independent variables which are determined by equilibrium conditions are the energy U and the volume V of the subsystem".

So, my second question (following directly from the first one) is this: The function G(T,P,N) apparently has no independent variables left! What independent variables are we talking about, then?

Evidently, I'm misunderstanding something important. Can you help me, please? Thank you in advance!

Edit: Maybe I forgot some important information needed to understand my question. I tried to clarify some points in the comments to the answers. However, thank you very much for your answers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are right in saying that $N$ is fixed since we impose that the spherical region of space that we are considering contains *exactly* $1$ mg of water.

If this was the usual discussion about equilibrium thermodynamics, you would be right: since the subsystem is in contact with a reservoir, $T$ and $P$ (and hence $V$) are constant, too.

But here Callen is explicitly considering ***fluctuations***, so this line of reasoning is not going to work. Let's see why (I will talk about temperature but the same is of course valid for pressure).

When we say that $T$ has a certain value we mean that it takes that value *on average*: in reality, there will always be fluctuations, i.e. if you were to measure $T$ accurately enough you would see something like this (average value in red):

[image]

These fluctuations are completely random from a macroscopic point of view, since they come from the microscopic dynamics of the system, which is not under our control. Moreover, the smaller the system, the larger the fluctuations (it can be shown that they are proportional to $1/\sqrt{N}$).

Callen talks about fluctuations in volume, but the concept is the same: $T$,$P$, and hence $V$ are all fluctuating; only $N$ is not since we fixed it by definition.

So, when we say that the system is in a in a free energy minimum, corresponding to a certain value of the three parameters $(T,N,P)$, we must understand that these values are actually fluctuating, and that the system is actually "wiggling around" in the minimum, continuously going to states $(T',P',N) \neq (T,N,P)$.

But every time it gets away from the minimum, the restoring mechanism coming from the condition that $G$ must be minimized comes into play, taking it back there.

Comment: Thank you valerio92. Your answer helped me to better understand also the other ones. Until now I always studied thermodynamic potentials in the context of equilibrium thermodynamics.

Comment: Correct me if my conclusions are wrong: when Callen shows a plot like [this one](http://casey.brown.edu/chemistry/misspelled-researh/crp/Edu/Documents/00_Chem201/images/Thermodynamic_potential_with_m.gif) saying that it displays G(T,P,N) for a fixed T, he is showing the values that G assumes while P (and thus the volume V, which is the varible actually displayed on the x axis) fluctuates.

Comment: Exactly. Thermodynamic equilibrium corresponds to the lower minimum, while the higher one corresponds to a metastable equilibrium, meaning that if you put the system there eventually a fluctuation will come that will take it back to the lowest minimum.

Comment: I've got only a question left: when the two minima of G  are equally deep, i.e. when we are at the boiling point, both states (liquid and gaseous) are accessible. Indeed, we can have a system at 373.15 K and 1 atm that contains both phases in equilibrium. But this means that the two minima, even if corresponding to different volumes V, have the same T and P. How is this possible?

Comment: Wait! Maybe I got it! After all, to the same T and P can correspond multiple values of V, but a finite number of them. I'm referring, e.g., to the non-monotonic plot of P as a function of V at constant T yelded by the Van der Waals law. And, of course, phase transitions occur only when we are in the region of the P-V plane where this non-monotonic behaviour is present.

Comment: Yes, exactly. Take a look [here](https://www.e-education.psu.edu/png520/sites/www.e-education.psu.edu.png520/files/graphics/figure0306.gif): at a phase transition, you can have same $T$ and $P$ but different $V$. The Van Der Walls equation of state is not completely reasonable here, but can be used to predict where you will find metastable states. But this is another story...Search "spinodal line" and "binodal line" if you are interested.

Answer (score 1):

Remember, the Gibbs free energy is related to the amount of reversible work that may be performed at constant temperature, T, and pressure, p.  For thermodynamic equilibrium, at a specified p and T, the Gibbs free energy is at a minimum.  The chemical potential is central to such considerations.  Restated, this potential is useful for calculating equilibrium chemical concentrations.

1) The Gibbs free energy has natural variables of p and T.  At constant p and T, the Gibbs free energy is depending on the extent of reaction, xi, to reach thermal equilibrium.  To minimize G, you differentiate with respect to xi.

2) G(p,T) = U + pV - TS. So, the internal energy and volume are determined by the equilibrium conditions.

Comment: I agree with point 1), but in this specific case Callen treats the small spherical subsystem as composed of **only one** chemical species, e.g. water. The book says that its Gibbs potential has got two minima, corresponding to the liquid state and to the gaseous one. We are slightly above 373.15 K, so the minimum corresponding to the gas is more deep than the other one and the subsystem will spend more time in this state, while undergoing incessant statistical fluctuations. So, there is no reaction between two or more species going on: only an omogeneous system choosing between two states.

Comment: **Changes of state (liquid to gas as here) are treated with the same formalism as chemical reactions.**  In your example you can find the equilibrium by dG/dV=0.  If there are two minima (one liquid, one gas) you might have metastable trapping, or a clear stable ground state, depending on the details of the system.  For water, the energy barrier between liquid and gas just above the STP boiling point is sufficiently small that instantaneous liquid will thermally activate back to gas.  I believe that is Callen's point in this example.

Comment: G has **one** equilibrium value, the other values of the function are not the equilibrium values.

Answer (score 1):

This is a very common misunderstanding regarding the stationarity of any of the thermodynamic potentials be it $S$ or $U$ or $G$, etc. For example, in your question the function $G(T, p, x_1,x_2,..$, a general Gibbs function whose independent variables are temperature, pressure, and anything else that may affect the system $x_1, x_2,...$ (e.g., chemical concentration, magnetic field, etc.,) is a *function* of these variables and the energy balance $dG = -SdT + Vdp +y_1dx_1 + y_2dx_2+..$ is true irrespective of whether the system is in equilibrium or not. Of course if it is in contact with a constant temperature heat source and a constant pressure work source so that during the energy exchange the system's temperature and pressure are constant then you can also write that $dG = y_1dx_1 + y_2dx_2+..$.

Again, the function $G$ is meaningful whether the system is or is not in equilibrium with its environment. The stationarity of $G$ means that if you have  system that is not in equilibrium *now* but it is also in contact with a constant temperature heat source and a constant pressure work source then it will evolve towards equilibrium by the *other* variables $x_1, x_2,..$ that minimize $G$ when it will be in equilibrium with its environment.

The $G(T,p,N)$ function you are referring to is for a *given* phase, say $G_1(T_1,p_1,N_1)$ so to achieve phase equilibrium between this and another phase, say $G_2(T_2,p_2,N_2)$ only the quantity $N_1+N_2$ is constant and $N_1$, thus $N_2$ is variable so that $G_1+G_2$ is minimized.

Comment: Like I wrote in the comment to user3742632, Callen treats the subsystem as a simple omogeneous system that has got to choose between two local minima of **the same G**. The big system, of course, has got both the liquid and the gaseous phases, but I think that the book is focusing on the _small_ spherical subsystem in order to treat it as omogeneous. Anyway, the G has to be only one because the book shows a plot almost identical to [this one](http://casey.brown.edu/chemistry/misspelled-researh/crp/Edu/Documents/00_Chem201/images/Thermodynamic_potential_with_m.gif).

Comment: My problem is: How can G even _have_ multiple values corresponding to the same T and P? For this reasoning to work, it is required that at the same T and P, G has two minima. But G is a function of T,P,N, which are all constants.

Comment: $G_1(T, p, x_k)$ has one minimum and $G_2(T, p, x_k)$ has *another* minimum because it is another function. These are different functions: one for phase 1 and one for phase 2. When the phases do not mix (e.g., liquid and steam of $H_2O$) then the stable state is somewhere on the tangent line (plane) connecting those minima.